# Are the effects of Yahweh's decision is Mike Carey's "Lucifer" seen in any other DC/Vertigo comic?

Tags: dc, comics, vertigo-comics, lucifer

During the events of *Lucifer*, Yahweh abdicates his position and gives power to Elaine Belloc, before leaving his Creation.

Are there any moments in the main DC continuity where the effects of this action are seen?

Comment: I don't think this continuity is shared by any other comic.

Comment: Thats not exactly true, "Sandman" and "Hellblazer" are definitely in the same continuity: Lucifer met Dream and Destiny on more than one occasion, Constantine was in the Lux and done a favour for Dream.